# Duplicate Indexes error using Informatica 10.4

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning, informatica

While running an informatica mapping in v10.4    I'm getting the following error.
The mapping essentially calls a complex stored procedure in Oracle to "swap out" a temporary file to a partitioned fact table.

```
CMN_1022 [
ORA-20014: FINISH_SP: ORA-20010: Duplicate Indexes: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00I
ORA-06512: at "DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG", line 1650
ORA-20010: Duplicate Indexes: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00I
ORA-06512: at "DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG", line 1292
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P00I
ORA-28604: table too fragmented to build bitmap index (172073921,57,56)
ORA-06512: at "DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG", line 1277
ORA-06512: at "DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG", line 1277
ORA-06512: at "DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG", line 1593
```

I do not know what this error means to Informatica.
Can anyone help me decipher it *SPECIFIC TO INFORMATICA*

Answer (score 2):

The problem is specific to Oracle, so not sure how to make the answer specific to Informatica, especially without being able to see the details of what the workflow is trying to do.

The `ORA-20014: FINISH_SP: ORA-20010: Duplicate Indexes:` error is a custom message from the application code. The real key appears to be here: `"ORA-28604: table too fragmented to build bitmap index (172073921,57,56)"`

It looks like Informatica is attempting to build an index - indirectly through the `DIMDW.FACT_EXCHANGE_PARTITION_PKG` package - and the process is throwing an error. A simple Google search on ORA-28604 yields the following:

```
ORA-28604: table too fragmented to build bitmap index (%s,%s,%s)
 *Cause:  The table has one or more blocks that exceed the maximum number
          of rows expected when creating a bitmap index. This is probably
          due to deleted rows. The values in the message are:
          (data block address, slot number found, maximum slot allowed)
 *Action: Defragment the table or block(s). Use the values in the message
          to determine the FIRST block affected. (There may be others).
```

Since this involves the physical fragmentation of the data in the Oracle database, you will almost certainly need to get the DBA involved to troubleshoot this further. Your Informatica workflow likely isn't going anywhere until this is corrected in the database.